# How should I permanently store the value of a JS variable on an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, onsubmit

I am recreating a cryptocurrency faucet with integrated gambling in plain HTML/CSS/JS to have a better perspective of how do they work and how the balance moves from `user` to the `site` step to step and to learn JS so I am trying to replicate three features such as deposits, roll a dice to get free balance and gamble.

And I faced 2 problems on the deposit:

1. When I browse through the 3 pages obviously the balance is reset to 0 as it does reload the .js file, how should I approach this exercise? Should I start using cookies? Is there a way to store values on current session or to achieve persistent values when browsing that 3 pages?

   2. The deposit form does not work on `route/deposit.html`, it adds value to the variable but it is not editing the current balance on the site, but on different URLs like `route/deposit.html?#` it does work.

```js
let myBalance=0;
let dAmount=0;

function deposit(){

    dAmount = Number(document.getElementById("dAmount").value);
    myBalance = myBalance + dAmount;
    document.getElementById("myBalance").innerHTML=myBalance;
}
```

```css
/* Style the header with a grey background and some padding */
.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 20px 10px;
  }
  
  /* Style the header links */
  .header a {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  
  /* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
  .header a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  /* Change the background color on mouse-over */
  .header a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }
  
  /* Style the active/current link*/
  .header a.active {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
  }
  
  /* Float the link section to the right */
  .header-right {
    float: right;
  }
  
  /* Add media queries for responsiveness - when the screen is 500px wide or less, stack the links on top of each other */
  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }
   /* Create a static faucet balance indicator */
  .faucetbalance{
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5%;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Faucet emulation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<script src="./test.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="#default" class="logo">SupaFaucet</a>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="./freeroll.html">Free BITS</a>
          <a href="#hilo">HI-LO</a>
          <a href="#deposit" class="active">Deposit</a>
          <a>Balance: <span id="myBalance">0</span> BITS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="faucetbalance">
            <a>Faucet Balance: <span>0</span> BITS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Deposit BITS</h1>
    <form onSubmit="deposit()">
        <label for="deposit">Deposit:</label><input id="dAmount" type="number">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: You can use localStorage,  save value and date creation. First one is always the not changed one.

Comment: @palaѕн I will read how to implement sessionStorage and change the "let myBalance" to get the value of 0 directly from the HTML page instead of setting it on the .JS document then, that should solve the issue. It should start at 0 and later get the last value if session still open. Thanks for the good push by the way! :)

Comment: @Raphael, that would imply having to reset the values, right? I am going with `sessionStorage` for now as it seems more accurate for a recreation. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You should use localStorage or sessionStorage.

Here is example

```
// Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Syntax for SAVING data to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Syntax for READING data from localStorage:

```
var lastname = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Syntax for REMOVING data from localStorage:

```
localStorage.removeItem("key");
```